# PHP session if !isset {} else die()

Tags: php, session, header, isset, die

I originally had this code (without die) but it would allow the page to be viewed.

I tried to add the die function, however it is just showing the blank page.

```
<?php require('dbcon.php');?>
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['adminauth']))
{
    header('login.php');
    die();
};
?>
```

Comment: I think you want to change: `header('login.php');` to `header('Location: login.php');` Also the `;` at the end of the if statement you normally don't write

Comment: Do read up on the subject http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rizier123 right, but one comment - HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs.

```
<?php require('dbcon.php');?>
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
if (!isset($_SESSION['adminauth'])) {
    $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
    $extra = 'login.php';
    header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
    die();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable your error output with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` then you see all your errors. There are some things. You should start your session at the top of the script and your header is not correct.

```
header('Location: login.php');
```

Otherwise you have an error.

Answer (score 0):

see PHP header [DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
<?php
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
  exit;
?>
```